# OpenCV - flat panorama to cubic or equirectangular projection?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl-es, map-projections, 360-panorama

*I'm stuck in this problem for about 2 months now, tried every relevant SO post, blog and tutorial I could find out there. please help:*

I have a flat panorama image, which I want to convert either into cubeMap or Equirectangular format. I've used some SO posts in order to create equirectangular image from a cubeMap and vice versa. And I can do that,But that all requires a 360º projected image in some form. Question is how to prepare the cubeMap from flat panorama at first place ?

I've also seen ways to do cubeMap / equirectangular projection to / from FishEye. But couldn't find if there's a way I can create equirectangular projection from a flat image.

equirectangular projection:

[image]

cubeMap Projection:

[image]

I can also convert between the two. But I don't know how to create any of the above in first place ? An openCV implementation would be preferable, but can also use OpenGLES code. Thanks.